# Унаследоваться от темы AppCompat

Tags: android, android-themes, android-appcompat

Не могу унаследовать тему от `AppCompat`таким способом:

```
<style name= "Theme.MyTheme" parent= "Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

</style>
```

Пишет

> no resourse found that matches the given name.

Хотя библиотеку подключил и в коде от ActionBarActivity наследуюсь без ошибок.

Comment: а если попробовать вот такую строчку `<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

Comment: Нет, пишет тоже самое. Может дело в том, что я программирую в AIDE на андроид планшете?

Comment: кстати, вполне может быть

Comment: И что делать? А можно тему как то программно создавать ?

Comment: `И что делать?` - в AIDE никогда не работал, но ИМХО- для серьезных проектов данная IDE не годится, да конечно круто лежа на диване программать прямо на планшете, но...переходите на десктоп=)

Comment: Я бы рад, но сейчас такой возможности нет.

Comment: "Хотя библиотеку подключил ..." вы подключили jar-ку?

Comment: compile files ('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')

Answer (score 2):

В AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

в styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

в build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

активити наследуйте от AppCompatActivity

По идее, все должно быть ок.

Comment: Я не могу так подключить зависимость пишет dependency ... not found. Кстати это только с андроид библиотеками например compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
 Предлагает скачать и установлюет без проблем. А любые com.android не хочет.  И поэтому я их качал отдельно и подключался как .jar

Comment: В SDK Manager -> Extras установлены Android Support Repository и Android Support Library?

Comment: Мы говорим про среду AIDE на андроид

Comment: Сорри, про то, что разработка на AIDE идет просмотрел. Значит подключаемый вами jar ('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar') не полный, т.е. не содержит ресурсов.

Comment: Подключал такой, какой сумел найти. Не понимаю почему любые библиотеки скачивает и подключает само, а андроидские нет.

Comment: А если взять непосредственно из [репозитория Google](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml) нужный [архив с библиотекой](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r23.0.1.zip), собрать нужный jar с ресурсами или подключить как модуль?

Comment: Нужный модуль это папка appcompat из архива? Не могу подключить. В build.gradle пишу compile project (':appcompat') в settings.gradle include ':app',':appcompat' папка appcompat рядом с app. Или нужно не так подключать?

Answer (score 0):

Было с ошибками

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

AIDE -> Add to project -> выбери что нужно (я выбрал v7:+  -  работает).

Для design также.

Test убрал совсем.

Получилось что  дублировались записи ... v7.23.0.1    и ...v7+. Строки что вверху (где 23) убрал совсем. Остались только новые. Заработало